# non-trivial non-repetitive aperiodic tiling of the plane

Tags: examples-counterexamples, discrete-geometry, tiling

Which is the less trivial example of non-repetitive aperiodic tiling of the plane you know?

I cannot come up with a famous non-repetitive tiling. Are there any?

A tiling is repetitive if for every pattern $P$ there's a radius $R$ such that for every point $x$, the ball $B_R(x)$ has a translate of $P$.

Comment: Last I heard, there is no known single connected tile which tiles the plane. Usually, it is done with a set of tiles.

Comment: In a lot of the English literature, for future reference, we tend to use the word periodic for repetitive tilings, but that is probably just me nitpicking.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews There are a few tilings, I believe, that are spiral shaped and made from a single tile, though I an having a hard time recalling which ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple? I guess take any Penrose tiling (or some other repetitive aperiodic tiling) and replace a single tile with the same tile but of a new colour, or if you want tiles to not be able to be labelled, just add a notch to one edge of a tile-tile intersection. This is a rather boring answer, but probably the simplest example.

If you want some kind of stronger property - say you want that for every patch $P$ there exists **no** $R$ such that every $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ has the patch $P$ somewhere in the ball $B_R(x)$ - then perhaps a [Pinwheel tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinwheel_tiling) is what you're after. It satisfies the above stronger non-repetitivity condition with respective to translations, but it is repetitive with respect to *Euclidean motions* (where you allow for translations follows by a small rotation).

(Credit for first image - [Charles Radin](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/radin/))

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A famous one is the [Penrose tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling):

[image]

Comment: I meant already in the context of aperiodic tilings. I edited the question with the definition of repetitivity.